# LinkedIn website share always showing 1 min read. Is there any way to remove the tag?

Tags: linkedin-api

I am using the following Linkedin API for sharing from my application.
https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=XX&title=XXXX&source=XXXXX. It is showing a '1 min read' tag. Is there any way to remove the tag?